# chrome mobile VS chrome desktop: different position of the same element

Tags: html, css

Trying to find an answer to why **chrome on mobile phone** shows the same code **differently** than **desktop chrome** (and firefox, edge, opera). The `<a>` text has a different position in `<div>` container.

PS. Ive marked "BOOKS" on the screenshots to make it more visual. On desktop view `<a>` is in the middle, on mobile - to the top.

desktop:

[image: desktop]

mobile:

[image: mobile]

HTML:

```
    <div class="topbar" id="tb-grad">
      <a class="logomain" id="lm-shad">BOOKS & DVD</a>
      <a></a>
      <a></a>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
   .topbar {
      max-width: 600px; 
      font-size: 40px;margin: auto; 
      border-radius: 10px;}

   .logomain {
      font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
      font-size: 40px;
      color: yellow;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through the exact same problem and after many tests and missed hours found that fonts change in Chrome Mobile X Chrome Desktop.

I know i may have arrived late, but if anyone experiences this problem try switching the font used for another. A good place to find fonts for this test may be the Google Fonts site.

Test some sources for you to observe this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish, you can control the highlight colors using the following:

```
::selection {
  background:#BBD3FD;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background:#BBD3FD;
}
```

This will ensure that the background color of the highlighted segment is the same across all devices.
`#BBD3FD` is the pale blue that Google Docs uses for its highlight background.

Comment: sorry i may have worded the question not clearly before. Ive corrected it now - its about the position of <a> in the <div>